# Registration of absent linkage

Tags: macos, hard-drive

I made a verification of HD of Macbook Snow Leopard (using disk utility) and I received those messages in the report:

Registration of absent linkage. 
Incorrect number of linkage recordings. 
Disable counting of volume files. T
he volume Macintosh HD is rotten and he/she needs to be repaired.

What should make?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I'm guessing this was auto-translated by Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repaired the HD: I boot my MacBook from the drive of CD with the disk of installation of the OS X 10.5, and applying the disk utility.

Sorry my (poor) english...

Obrigado !